# How to get more detail about error when element not presented, Nightwatch.js?

Tags: nightwatch.js

I using Nightwatch.js + Selenium for acceptance testing and it generates html report after finish.
And sometimes when some element not presented on the page - Nightwatch will return an error, so, this code:

```
.waitForElementPresent('.block', 15000)
```

will return this error:

> Timed out while waiting for element to be present for 15000 milliseconds. - Expected "found" but got: "not found"

I want to see more details about element which not presented

Comment: Run night watch with the -v flag

Comment: It will return the current version of Nightwatch?

Comment: Ahh sorry, --verbose, not -v (which is version)

Comment: @AlexR, thank you, it helped, and now I searching for - how can I put path to the screenshot into nightwatch runner, it's needed for my custom reporter.Could you help me?

Comment: see http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#test-settings.  That will explain how to set up the config file (including screenshot info).  I'm not positive it's available in the runner, but you can just add it to the globals data and access globals from the runner

Comment: hi @AlexR, how to do in visual studio code?

Answer (score 0):

I really do not get the point,what do you want to know more?
The elements is not found so that it return you not found.

Before you go to code, open the browser, press F12 and find ".block" in element tab, make sure the element is present/visible then code ,or you just right-click on the element you want then chose copy selector.

If you want more detail about the element,go to console tab,paste this one and you will see the detail of '.block' element.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.block')
```